# Why is it easy to separate the cotton wool from the roots of young plants grown in cotton?

Tags: plant-anatomy, growth, seeds

In my book it is said that if we grow Maize and Gram seeds in wet cotton, after the seeds are sprouted it is easy to separate the cotton wool from the roots of young plants.

My question is why is it comparatively harder to separate roots from soil while it is easy for cotton wool?